# Using 'async' and neglecting to invoke 'callback'

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I'm relatively new to node.js, wondering how to make my asynchronous code more reliable. Focusing on code that uses 'async' (no promises yet, due to legacy reasons).

One of my reliability concerns is failing to invoke callbacks. E.g.

```
async.series([
       function(callback){
           if(..)
              console.log("invalid input, try again"); // BUG: NO CALLBACK!
           else
              callback(null, 'ok');
       },
       function(callback){
           ...
       }
  ],
  function(err,result){ handleErrorOrResult(err,result);} // MIGHT NOT BE REACHED
);
```

This code may never complete (never reach 'handleErrorOrResult') and I won't even know that anything went wrong. Since this pit is easy to fall into, I wonder whether there are ready-made library solutions for it? Any ideas would be welcome, but one direction might be timeouts: invoke some error handler if the whole thing isn't completed within, say, 5 minutes.

Thanks very much

Comment: Timeouts is your only option, though i wouldn't consider that reliable.

Comment: thanks. Could you please tell if there are any ready-made library solutions for it? I kind of expected to find  something like  async.series( functions, timeout, callback) but there's no such timeout option...

Comment: Nope, i'm not aware of any. Use a setTimeout that throws an error if it isn't stopped, and stop it in the complete.

Comment: However, i find such code to be pointless. If you're going to take the time to catch forgetting to add a callback, just go through and make sure you didn't forget to add a callback.

Comment: LOL good point, but obviously I wanted this 'safely net' for complex cases where I invoke other people's code who invoke other people's code, and the bug is in some 'IF' that is rarely reached - you get the point. But thanks anyway, your reply helped :)

Comment: FYI, there are NO legacy reasons I'm aware of in node.js to avoid promises.  Just get yourself a library like Bluebird and you can have full-scale promises in any version of node.js.  That's the beauty of node.js development.  You control the exact environment you're running in so you can often install a polyfill library to get new features even if you aren't upgrading your version of node.js.

Comment: FYI, One of the biggest reasons to use promises is that it makes the handling of errors in async callbacks a ton easier.  You can just throw an exception and it will automatically propagate the error back to a higher level error handler, aborting other sequences in the promise chain that have not executed yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your own wrapper for it that implements a timeout.

```
var myAsync = {
  series: function (callbacks, timeout, done) {
    var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
      done("Maximum Time Exceeded for method!");
    }, timeout);
    async.series(callbacks, function () {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      done.apply(this, arguments);
    });
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
myAsync.series(functions, functions.length * 500, callback);
```

Comment: You could even take this further and have the timeout be a per function  timeout, so if any one function takes longer than the timeout it would call `next(error)`

Comment: How does throwing from a `setTimeout()` callback do anything useful?  The exception goes into the timer system and is dutifully ignored and does not affect any other code.  See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/pb1y3y8z/

Comment: The odd thing about your solution now is that it reports the timeout to a callback function, but the async operations continue on as if nothing changed.  This concept still seems flawed.

Comment: That's like you saying that there is no way to handle errors properly in async code.  There is always a way to do it.  Not as simple as sync code, but always a way to do it.  This answer is just incomplete.